# CUDA runtime api interception

Tags: cuda

Can anyone explain how to intercept calls to CUDA Runtime API?
I am a newbie and I have read a bit about linux library interception.
I want to use the same concept so that I can intercept Cuda Runtime Api.

Answer (score 3):

The CUPTI SDK included in the CUDA Toolkit provides support for enabling callbacks on enter and exit of the CUDA runtime API. It is possible to do some modification to state in the callbacks but the current callback system does not allow you to modify the value of the parameters or to skip the real function.

If you need the ability to modify input and output parameters then I recommend you generate an interception layer. Doxygen perlmod and a fairly small perl script can be used to generate an interception layer.

I believe the ocelot source code has a full CUDA runtime interception layer.

On Linux you can use LD_PRELOAD to insert your interception layer into the application.